# How is Spring Cloud Gateway different from Zuul?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-gateway

I have been using [Zuul](https://github.com/Netflix/zuul/wiki) as the edge service and API Gateway. Recently I have noticed that Spring Cloud Platform release [Spring Cloud Gateway](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/). What is the difference between the two gateways? Why is the Zuul not extended to support the functionalities in S-C-Gateway? What was the driving factor for a new library altogether? When should it be used?

Comment: Could you share the Spring [Boot] version you're refering to?

Answer (score 232, accepted):

I am the author of spring cloud gateway. Zuul is built on servlet 2.5 (works with 3.x), using blocking APIs. It doesn't support any long lived connections, like websockets.

Gateway is built on Spring Framework 5, Project Reactor and Spring Boot 2 using non-blocking APIs. Websockets are supported and it's a much better developer experience since it's tightly integrated with Spring.

Comment: On Sept/Oct  2016,  Netflix released Zuul 2. It is a non-blocking and asynchronous solution. The major architectural difference between Zuul 2 and Zuul 1 is that Zuul 2 is running on an asynchronous and non-blocking framework, using Netty.

Comment: They have not released zuul 2, they announced it. The current development is being done on the 2.1 branch.

Comment: @spencergibb Is the performance problems of spring-cloud-gateway mentioned in [this](https://engineering.opsgenie.com/comparing-api-gateway-performances-nginx-vs-zuul-vs-spring-cloud-gateway-vs-linkerd-b2cc59c65369) comparison solved? 229ms (scg) compared to 29ms (Zuul1) on 8core-16gb machine is not really useful.

Comment: Zuul 2.1.1 has been released on April 13, 2018. It is asynchronous and non-blocking.

Comment: Is there any difference in performance between Cloud Gateway vs. Netflix Zuul 2?

Comment: So now that Zuul 2 is also asynchronous, is it useful for web sockets over stomp or still Spring Cloud Gateway is recommended @spencergibb ?

Comment: Spring Cloud will not integrate zuul 2

Comment: For me, the websocket support is a huge thing, much needed if you are building an app which needs to show real time responses.