# Maven Build- [ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zuul:jar is missing. @ line 28, column 15

Tags: spring-boot, maven, microservices

POM.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.ge.aviation.clearview</groupId>
    <artifactId>clearview-api-gateway</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.24</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>clearview-api-gateway</name>
    <description>API Gateway</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zuul</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
           <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
           <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.20131108.vaadin1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Dalston.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <finalName>clearviewcmr-gateway-service</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


</project>
```

-> Zuul jar is missing as per error though dalston version is defined 
[ERROR]

Downloading from spring-snapshots: https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-dependencies/Dalston.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-cloud-dependencies-Dalston.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:pom:Dalston.BUILD-SNAPSHOT from/to spring-snapshots (https://repo.spring.io/snapshot): Transfer failed for https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-dependencies/Dalston.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-cloud-dependencies-Dalston.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom ProxyInfo{host='cinext11.proxy.corporate.ge.com', userName='null', port=80, type='https', nonProxyHosts='null'} @ line 111, column 16
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zuul:jar is missing. @ line 28, column 15

Comment: Please try to ask a more clear question. What are you trying to achieve, what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: The version you are trying to find does not exist: https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-dependencies/

Comment: @TobiO , As given above error message has been thrown while I use MVN clean install.

Comment: @SiKing the link provided in your comment does contain Dalston.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/  version which is used in my POM.xml.

Comment: But the missing dependency, as per the error, is version "Greenwich.SR1". This is probably being pulled as a transitive dependency.

Comment: I have specified the latest error message which says version is missing though cloud version mentioned as Dalston-cloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dalston release train for Spring-Cloud was released in 2016.
You shouldn't use its SNAPSHOT versions anymore.

There is a Dalston.SR5 release from December 2017, which should result in:

```
spring-cloud-dependencies:Dalston.SR5
-> spring-cloud-netflix-dependencies:1.3.6.RELEASE
-> spring-cloud-starter-zuul:1.3.6.RELEASE
-> zuul-core:1.3.0
```

If you're starting with a new project and you have spring boot 2.2.x, you can also use the latest release train (Hoxton). Spring Cloud never upgraded to Netflix Zuul 2, however, but released an alternative: Spring-Cloud-Gateway. See [How is Spring Cloud Gateway different from Zuul?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47092048/how-is-spring-cloud-gateway-different-from-zuul/47094859#47094859)

Bottom line: avoid depending on spring-snapshots or spring-milestones repositories unless you need bleeding edge releases.